# Where can I get order book data?

Tags: market-data

In my experience trading in asian markets, I have found a few resources that conduct calculations on order books.  They are able to provide the size and real time movements on specific types of orders classified based on their size.  I can then see on the dashboard how much individual investors are buying, how much institutions are buying, etc.  I was wondering if there are similar platforms that can provide this data in US stock markets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have seen.

Comment: https://data.eastmoney.com/zjlx/  it is in chinese, but you can use google translate to see what is happening.  The top left graph tells you the order amount by size graphed against time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally good quality data is not free. In academia, [LOBSTER](https://lobsterdata.com/) data is frequently used for orderbook modeling/research. You can check out their [sample files](https://lobsterdata.com/info/DataSamples.php) to examine their data quality. Data description is [provided here](https://lobsterdata.com/info/HowDoesItWork.php) and if satisfied they have a subscription option.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I was trying for months to find such data.  Thank you a million times over.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in cryptocurrency data, here are some options:

- Binance provides free, but on-request, [futures orderbook data](https://www.binance.com/en/landing/data) in csv files. This is probably the best free resource currently, as orderbook data are almost exclusively paid and rather expensive.
- Crypto-Lake.com provides cheap [orderbook data](https://crypto-lake.com/) via S3/Python api. They have some small [free dataset](https://crypto-lake.com/free-data/) too.
- Tardis.dev provides [data plans](https://tardis.dev/#pricing) with better data coverage, but much higher price tag. They have Python/NodeJS/HTTP api.